# SQL Server incorrect syntax near ','

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having problems with my SQL Server query and keep running into the issue of incorrect syntax. The main issue I am having is that it just tells me it is near ',' but I have many commas in my query and can't find which one it is arguing about. Is there a way to determine which it is arguing about? Also, I am running this through Business Intelligence Development Studio.

```
select ud.emailaddress, 
ud.firstname, 
ud.lastname, 
ud.createdate,
a.masterstatcode,
a.state, 
a.agencyname,
c.campaigncode,
'MNY' + CONVERT(varchar(10), ua.quipid) CashCode,
case when ua.activeuser = 0 then 'No' when ua.activeuser = 1 then 'Yes' else '' end as activeUser,
case when a.activeagency = 0 then 'No' when a.activeagency = 1 then 'Yes' else '' end as activeAgency, 
case WHEN a.State in ('AK', 'MT', 'WA', 'OR', 'ID') then 'Northwest' 
         WHEN a.State in ('CA') then 'California'
         WHEN a.State in ('AZ', 'CO', 'NM', 'NV', 'UT', 'WY') then 'Mountain'
         WHEN a.State in ('AR', 'KS', 'LA', 'MO', 'OK', 'TX') then 'Central'
         WHEN a.State in ('IA', 'IN', 'MI', 'MN', 'ND', 'NE', 'SD', 'WI', 'IL') then 'Midwest'
         WHEN a.State in ('NH', 'VT', 'ME', 'CT', 'NY', 'MA') then 'Northeast' 
         WHEN a.State in ('KY', 'MD', 'OH', 'PA', 'VA', 'WV', 'DE') then 'Mid Atlantic'
         WHEN a.State in ('AL', 'FL', 'GA', 'MS', 'NC', 'SC', 'TN') then 'Southeast' 
         ELSE 'Other' end as Region,
tm.lastname as TerritoryManagerlast,
tm.firstname as TerritoryManagerfirst,
count(distinct ud.userId) as QuotersEnrolled,
SUM(r.RewardAmount) AS PaidRewards,
SUM(CASE WHEN r.QuoteDate is not null and (r.Tier != 'NSTD' OR r.Tier is null) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS PoliciesQuoted,
SUM(CASE WHEN r.policyissuedate is not null and r.RewardAmount > 0 then 1 else 0 END) AS PoliciesIssued
```

--EDIT--
Sorry, I purposely left out the from clause because the error should not be involved in those. I set this up in Business Intelligence Development Studio with a report already complete with parameters and designed it. The query works when running it in SSMS and even works when I choose only one TerritoryManager parameter. The error occurs when I choose multiple territory managers, which I find odd.

I am fairly new to using Business Intelligence Development Studio (BIDS), and since I have to express parameters with an @ symbol I cannnot debug the same queries in SSMS without reworking it to remove the @ symbols. I was wondering if there was a way to debug in BIDS? Thanks for the help.

For reference, here is the rest of the query:

```
from Agencies a
join TerritoryManagers tm on a.territorymanagerid = tm.id
    left join UserAgency ua on a.Id = ua.AgencyId
left join UserDetails ud on ua.UserId = ud.UserId
    left join CampaignAgency ca on ca.agencyId = a.id
left join Rewards r on ud.UserId = r.UserId AND (r.RewardType = 'Sale' OR r.RewardType = 'Quote' OR r.RewardType is null) 
                       AND r.campaignId = ca.campaignId
    left join Campaigns c on c.id = ca.campaignId and c.campaigncode in (@CampaignCode)

where a.Id <> 5 AND a.Id <> 6 
and a.id in (Select ca.agencyid from CampaignAgency ca inner join Campaigns c2 on ca.CampaignId = c2.Id and C2.CampaignCode in (@CampaignCode))
            and ua.quipid is not null
and a.TerritoryManagerID in (SELECT Id FROM TM_CTE UNION ALL SELECT CASE WHEN @TM in (0) Then ID else 99999 end FROM TerritoryManagers )
and ua.activeuser in (@activeUser)

Group by a.MasterStatCode, a.AgencyName, a.State, a.TerritoryManagerId, tm.firstname, tm.lastname, a.ActiveAgency, ud.EmailAddress, ud.firstname, ud.lastname, c.campaigncode, ua.QuipId, ua.activeuser, ud.createdate
```

Comment: So you have too many commas for you to parse through but so you'd like strangers on the internet to do it for you?

Comment: Take out all of the items you are selecting and add them in one by one until you come across the culprit?

Comment: Also, it may not be that the error *is* the comma, it's just saying there is a problem *near* the comma.

Comment: clearly you are missing a FROM.....

Comment: Try to delete some part of query and run it again, than other part and so on, untill you find where was error and will be able to correct it. It will help you with all similar problems.

Comment: @TMcKeown, I saw that too, but I thought perhaps he didn't include it on purpose

Comment: @SlyRaskal: Which would turn out pretty pointless if the issue wasn't in the posted part.

Comment: @AndriyM: Not if you start with a basic query, adding one join at a time, adding a couple columns to select clauses at a time, adding where conditions one at a time, etc., until you either come across the issue or have something that still works.  It's not that hard.  Since he didn't post anything but the select clause, that is why I stated what I did.

Comment: @SlyRaskal: And yet it does turn out the posted snippet actually [doesn't have a syntactic issue](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/27397) (just saying).

Comment: @AndriyM, thanks for doing that for him.  I simply didn't want to waste my time doing something that he could have done on his own in the hope that he learns the proper way of approaching problem solving because from what it sounds like, he hadn't applied much, if any, analysis to his query before he posted here saying he had an issue.  That is the underlying point I was trying to make. Cheers.

Comment: I think you're getting so much grief because these "old hands", with a lot of experience with SQL Server, have **GOTTEN USED TO** almost-useless error messages.  It would be GREAT if, when you slipped up and put WHERE after ORDER BY, SQL Server would tell you something useful, like "WHERE must precede ORDER BY"... but no... "incorrect syntax near ," is about as much as you get! We've learned, the hard way, that IT TAKES WORK to figure out these errors. Some think you should already know that, and have already tried the methodical suggestions.  (Another suggestion: debug SQL in Mgmt Studio.)

Comment: @Doug_Ivison, you bring up some great points and emphasize the methodical practices I was trying to teach, but didn't explicitly state, breaking down the issue into small pieces that are easier to manage and assess.  I think too many SO members give answers, but the poster doesn't really *learn* anything.  And that doesn't help anyone in the end.

Comment: As SlyRaskal indicated, if you cut and paste the SQL into SSMS and click on _Parse_ it reports no issues. Is there anything else with which we may assist?

Answer (score 0):

Your question "--EDIT--" made all the difference:  
First, combining your original error message (in the question title), with your new comments (esp. `error occurs when I choose multiple territory managers`), it starts sounding like a problem with trying to give a list to an `IN` clause, where quotes or commas are not arranged properly... perhaps something intended to be **code** is being interpreted as part of the **values**, or vice versa.

Next, looking at the rest of the code (esp. your `WHERE` clause), there is indeed an 'IN' clause for territory managers, with a parameter passed to it:

> and a.TerritoryManagerID in (SELECT Id FROM TM_CTE UNION ALL SELECT CASE WHEN @TM in (0) Then ID else 99999 end FROM TerritoryManagers )

So, the next question is:  What exactly does that `(0)` look like, when it contains 1 territory manager, and when it contains multiple territory managers?

Passing multiple values to feed an `IN` clause may need to be done indirectly... you might end up either: 
(1) using *dynamic SQL* (creating the `SELECT` as a string, then using `EXECUTE` or `sp_executesql` to execute that string), or 
(2) making the territory managers list a short table, maybe even passing that table as a parameter to the stored procedure... then (2a) using `IN (SELECT t FROM t_list)` (where `t_list` is the table), or (2b) `JOIN`ing to that table.

Hope that helps...